# EditText Field not working good when run the app

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Developing an app which have 9 edittext fields.
Have a problem with edittext field. It looks fine on xml layout but when i run the app on emulator these field are all around the screen. And when run on real mob they even look worse .(they place themself all around the screen not where i set them )..Don't know what to do. Here is the xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/zmal"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/showz"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:fontFamily="bold"
        android:textColor="#fefdfd"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calc"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/calbu" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/zktmal6"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal8"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/zktmal8"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal9"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/zktmal5"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/zktmal4"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/zktmal9"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/calc"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/zktmal1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/zktmal3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/zktmal10"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/zktmal2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Any screen shot how you want to place your layout? What do you mean by all over the screen?

Comment: Want to place them in a line.. From top to bottom. Can you tell me is their any other unit of size ( except dp ) for relative layout.

Comment: use linear layout vertical with the button sizes wrap content

Comment: LinearLayout with vertical orientation.

Comment: In linear layout how to place a textfield according to you wish. Drag and drop is not working.

Comment: @NoumanGhaffar see my answer check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the width and the height of the items you want.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showz"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="bold"
    android:textColor="#fefdfd"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/calbu" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal6"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal8"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal5"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"

    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal4"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal9"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal3"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal10"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal2"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have changed some and you can see the difference. and remove `android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` two lines if using `LinearLayout`

Comment: In this you can get all the elements in vertical order. Thanks

Comment: not working..all the edittext boxes and button fill the whole screen and make background invisible.

Answer (score 0):

In the xml you set:`android:layout_above="@+id/YourViewName"` I'm think it should be `android:layout_above="@id/YourViewName"` because you are specifing an id you already created not trying to generate a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Create one by one from bottom to top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="ExtraText" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showz"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:fontFamily="bold"
    android:textColor="#fefdfd"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calc"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal9"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/calc"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal8"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal9"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal6"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal8"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal5"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal6"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal4"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal5"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal3"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal2"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zktmal10"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```